# Custom field not displaying in edit mode

Tags: custom-fields

CiviCRM 5.12.4-5.13.4
PHP 7.1 - 7.2
Joomla 3.9.6
MySQL 5.6

Hi,
After updating Civi to 5.12.4, I cannot edit custom fields in contacts, also creating and editing fields in Administer 'Edit Field' brings the pop-up with the title and blank page.

Changed PHP version from 7.2 to 7.1/7.0, still the same issue. Can't see any errors in the console or error log files.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks, V.

Comment: Hi welcome to Civicrm stack exchange. Do you mean civi 5.13.4 (The latest version?)
What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM logs if it has logged any error when you try to perform some actions on the custom field?